# Recurly JS API version 2.7.0 - Could not verify Recurly's SSL certificate

Tags: php, ssl, recurly

I'm running xampp on my localhost Windows 10

- Apache/2.4.7
- PHP 5.5.9

When I try to call Recurly PHP API (API version = 2.7.0), it returns this error

> Could not verify Recurly's SSL certificate.

https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php

It worked fine when I used previous version of recurly library (API version = 2.5.3).

In README file of this API repository the following line is there, but not sure how to that on Windows.

> Recurly_Client::$CACertPath = '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem';

Can you anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: You'll need to point it to a certificate bundle. See here perhaps: http://neurotechnics.com/blog/ssl-ca-bundles-for-curl-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the path to your certificate.

This is the path that should be included in Recurly_Client::$CACertPath = 'path/to/my/cert';"